# whether every normal subgroup is characteristic?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group. A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called *characteristic* if $\varphi(H)\subset H$ for all automorphisms $\varphi$ of $G$.

Now it is easy to show that every characteristic group is normal, as for every inner automorphism $\tau_g$, $\tau_g(H)\subset H$, i.e. $g^{-1}Hg\subset H$ for all $g\in G$.

Is that converse true? That is, **whether every normal subgroup is characteristic?**

Comment: Look at the Klein-four-group, all subgroups are normal but none of them is characteristic

Comment: @PeterMelech A little pedantic, but you might want to specify that this only holds for the nontrivial subgroups.

Comment: $(x,y) \mapsto (y,z)$ permutes the two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Sebastian Schoennenbeck Thanks,of course all non-trivial subgroups!

Comment: @PeterMelech Thanks. I did not know about the Klein four group. I read it up. It is helpful for a lot of problems!

Comment: Do you know about abelian groups that are not cyclic? Klein four is just one of them. Indeed, elementary abelian groups are all vector spaces over finite fields, so they're full of normal noncharacteristic subgroups.

Comment: @anon It is obvious that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. But how does it follow from being a vector space over a finite field that it is bound to have non-characteristic subgroups?

Comment: Because linear transformations can change one vector subspace to another. To paint a mental picture, imagine rotating a line in the plane. For a sketch of an algebraic justification, note every subspace has a basis that can be extended to a basis for the whole space, and the general linear group acts transitively on the bases of the whole space (since, after applying a matrix to the coordinate basis, the new basis is just the set of column vectors).

Comment: has nothing to do with the group being finite. Beyond that, if $L$ is a one-dimensional subspace of a vector space $V$ of greater dimension over a field $k$, then $L=kv$ is mappable via an automorphism of $V$ to any other one-dimensional $kw$.